# show the sum of total time of a state in highcharts

Tags: javascript, time, highcharts, sum

We are showing the state of a switch (On/Off) in highcharts. Now the question is whether and how it is possible to get the total "on"-time for a day, a week, a month etc. 
E.g. switch No1 is open on Monday from 2-3 a.m, from 6-8 a.m., and from 3-5 p.m. On Tuesday the switch is open from.... 
We would like to have a chart which is showing us that switch No 1 was open on Monday for 5 hours, on Tuesday for...hours, etc. 
To define whether the sum should be on a daily, weekly, monthly basis it would be nice to have some possibility for a choice.

I hope I made my point clear?

Comment: Have you tried something so far ?

Comment: what is the type of chart you are trying to represent the data on?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just process this based on the data and not worry about the chart? You have already sent the data to the chart - so you have it. Get the range you want, parse your data, spit out the total "on" or "off" time. If the data is coming from a DB even better as you can do this query in the DB. You can use the visible range of the chart to set your start/end times for use in the query.